# Добавить треугольник polygon svg через style css

Tags: javascript, css3, svg, css-animation, svg-animation

```css
g {
  fill: #fdd;
  transition: 500ms;
}
g:hover {
  fill: wheat;
}
text {
  pointer-events: none;
}
.pol{
clip-path: polygon(270px 60px, 250px 80px, 285px 95px);
}
```

```html
<svg>
 <defs>
    <filter id="shadow" x=-50% y=-50% width=200% height=200%>
       <feDropShadow dx="5" dy="5" stdDeviation="5" 
                     flood-color="#333" flood-opacity=".1" />
    </filter>
  </defs>
  
  <g>
    <rect filter="url(#shadow)"  
          x="10" y="10" width="270" height="70" rx="25" />
    <polygon points="270 60  250 80  285 95" />   
  </g>
  <text x="140" y="50" text-anchor="middle">example text</text>
</svg>

<svg>
 <defs>
    <filter id="shadow" x=-50% y=-50% width=200% height=200%>
       <feDropShadow dx="5" dy="5" stdDeviation="5" 
                     flood-color="#333" flood-opacity=".1" />
    </filter>
  </defs>
  
  <g>
    <rect filter="url(#shadow)"  
          x="10" y="10" width="270" height="70" rx="25" />
    <polygon class="pol" />   
  </g>
  <text x="140" y="50" text-anchor="middle">Пример с clip-path</text>
</svg>
```

Делаю через стиль меняя эту строчку `<polygon points="270 60  250 80  285 95" />` на эту `<polygon class="pol" />` но не выходит

Comment: points это attribute. Через CSS можно поменять style, но не attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариант CSS. Ответ не совсем по теме, но возможно кому-то пригодится.

```css
.block {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 200px; min-height: 40px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #ffdddd; box-shadow: 3px 10px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.05);
}

.block::after {
  content: ''; position: absolute;
  bottom: 2px; right: 15px; width: 80px; height: 100px;
  border-radius: 20px 0px 5px 0px;
  transform: skew(30deg, 30deg) rotate(0deg);
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 50%, #ffdddd 50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="block"></div>
```

В качестве бонуса плюс небольшая динамика носика =)

```css
.block {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 200px; min-height: 40px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #ffdddd; box-shadow: 3px 10px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.05);
}

.block::after {
  content: ''; position: absolute;
  bottom: 2px; right: 15px; width: 0px; height: 0px;
  border-radius: 20px 0px 5px 0px;
  transform: skew(30deg, 30deg) rotate(0deg);
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 50%, #ffdddd 50%);
  transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
}
.block:hover::after {
  width: 80px; height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="block"></div>
```

Comment: Хороший, полезный ответ. В ручную делаете или используете какие-то онлайн инструменты их полно в сети, для градиентов, `box-shadow`, clip-path  И еще мне интересно,хоть и это не входит в вопрос, ну в качестве бонуса, - носик можно сделать динамичным при наведении

Comment: согласен, особенно это в SVG заметно. Всё ищут волшебную палочку, кнопочку, в виде JS  фреймворка, нажав на которую можно SVG заставить заработать. Но если в SVG ошибка, никакой фреймворк не поможет

Comment: Нормально получилось, мне понравилось

Answer (score 3):

**Для изменения контура тултипа можно попробовать использовать анимацию атрибута `d` `path`**

В основе анимации лежит плавный переход из начального `path` овала без стрелки к финальному `path` со стрелкой.

По наведению курсора меняется цвет тултипа и при клике вырастает стрелка.
При  повторном клике стрелка плавно исчезает.

```js
var tooltip = document.getElementById("svg1"),
  close = document.getElementById('close'),
  open = document.getElementById("open");
let flag = true;
tooltip.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (flag == true) {
    close.beginElement();
    flag = false;
  } else {
    open.beginElement();
    flag = true;
  }
});
```

```css
.pol {
fill: #fdd;
stroke-width:2;
stroke:#000"
transition: 500ms;
filter:url(#shadow);
}
:hover.pol {
 fill: wheat;
 }
 text {
  font-size:24px;
  fill:#7A7A7A;
  pointer-events: none;
  text-anchor:middle;
    }
```

```html
<svg id="svg1" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    width="300" height="100" viewBox="0 0 300 100" > 
   <defs>
   <filter id="shadow" x="-20%" y="-20%" width="150%" height="150%">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="2"/>
      <feOffset dx="3" dy="3"/>
      <feMerge>
        <feMergeNode/>
        <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/>
      </feMerge>
    </filter>
  </defs>  
<path class="pol" d="m35 10h220c13.9 0 21.9 11.2 25 25 0 0 3.1 20.9-1.8 29.4C273.6 72.5 266.8 80 255 80 192.3 79.8 35 80 35 80 21.2 80 10 68.9 10 55V35C10 21.2 21.2 10 35 10Z">
    <animate id="close"
   attributeName="d"
   begin="indefinite"
   restart="whenNotActive"
   dur="0.5s"
   fill="freeze"
   values="
    m35 10h220c13.9 0 21.9 11.2 25 25 0 0 3.1 20.9-1.8 29.4C273.6 72.5 266.8 80 255 80 192.3 79.8 35 80 35 80 21.2 80 10 68.9 10 55V35C10 21.2 21.2 10 35 10Z;
   
   m35 10h220c13.9 0 21.9 11.2 25 25 0 0-0.2 16.3 0 29.4C280.9 132.2 282.9 79.8 255 80 192.3 80.4 35 80 35 80 21.2 80 10 68.9 10 55V35C10 21.2 21.2 10 35 10Z" />   
    
   <animate id="open"
   attributeName="d"
   begin="indefinite"
   restart="whenNotActive"
   dur="0.5s"
   fill="freeze"
   values="
   m35 10h220c13.9 0 21.9 11.2 25 25 0 0-0.2 16.3 0 29.4C280.9 132.2 282.9 79.8 255 80 192.3 80.4 35 80 35 80 21.2 80 10 68.9 10 55V35C10 21.2 21.2 10 35 10Z;
   
   m35 10h220c13.9 0 21.9 11.2 25 25 0 0 3.1 20.9-1.8 29.4C273.6 72.5 266.8 80 255 80 192.3 79.8 35 80 35 80 21.2 80 10 68.9 10 55V35C10 21.2 21.2 10 35 10Z"
     />  
        
 </path> 
      <text x="140" y="50">Пример с clip-path</text>

</svg>
```

**Можно попробовать использовать более интересную форму тултипа**

```css
.container {
  width:75vw;
  height:75vh;
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <svg id="svg1" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"viewBox="0 0 240 240">
 <defs>
   <filter id="shadow" x="-20%" y="-20%" width="150%" height="150%">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="2"/>
      <feOffset dx="3" dy="3"/>
      <feMerge>
        <feMergeNode/>
        <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/>
      </feMerge>
    </filter>
  </defs>  
      <g  filter="url(#shadow)" transform="scale(1)">
        <path d="m20 10c-5.5 0-10 4.5-10 10l0 50c0 5.5 4.5 10 10 10l21.4 0.2-0.1-0.1c4.2 0.1 11.3 0.1 11.3 0.1l7.7 0 8.9 0c16.6 0 7.2-2 5.5-0.3L78 80.2 100 80c5.5 0 10-4.5 10-10l0-50c0-5.5-4.5-10-10-10z" style="fill:dodgerblue;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round; fill-opacity:0.5">
          <animate id="an_path"
          attributeName="d"
          values="
    m20 10c-5.5 0-10 4.5-10 10l0 50c0 5.5 4.5 10 10 10l21.4 0.2-0.1-0.1c4.2 0.1 11.3 0.1 11.3 0.1l7.7 0 8.9 0c16.6 0 7.2-2 5.5-0.3L78 80.2 100 80c5.5 0 10-4.5 10-10l0-50c0-5.5-4.5-10-10-10z;
      
      
    m20 10c-5.5 0-10 4.5-10 10l0 50c0 5.5 4.5 10 10 10L41.4 80.2 37.3 75.7c-2.4-2.3 0.9-4 2-2.2L59.9 95.1 80.3 73.3c1.6-1.7 3.7 0.5 1.9 2.1L78 80.2 100 80c5.5 0 10-4.5 10-10l0-50c0-5.5-4.5-10-10-10z;
    
    m20 10c-5.5 0-10 4.5-10 10l0 50c0 5.5 4.5 10 10 10l21.4 0.2-0.1-0.1c4.2 0.1 11.3 0.1 11.3 0.1l7.7 0 8.9 0c16.6 0 7.2-2 5.5-0.3L78 80.2 100 80c5.5 0 10-4.5 10-10l0-50c0-5.5-4.5-10-10-10z;
          
   
   m20 10c-5.5 0-10 4.5-10 10l0 50c0 5.5 4.5 10 10 10L41.4 80.2 37.3 75.7c-2.4-2.3 0.9-4 2-2.2L59.9 95.1 80.3 73.3c1.6-1.7 3.7 0.5 1.9 2.1L78 80.2 100 80c5.5 0 10-4.5 10-10l0-50c0-5.5-4.5-10-10-10z"
          begin="svg1.click"
          dur="6s"
          repeatCount="1"
          fill="freeze"
          restart="whenNotActive">
          </animate>
        </path>
        <text x="30" y="50" font-size="18" fill="white">click me </text>
      </g>
    </svg>
  </div>
```

Comment: Он хочет через css добавлять поинты как координаты для polygon

Comment: @MaximLensky Я предложил, как вариант, может автор и не знает о такой возможности, понравится, возьмет на вооружение

Comment: он за последние сутки три вопроса задал о таком балуне ..посмтои в его истории - думаю что ему надо что то а что не ясно

Comment: @MaximLensky Ну вот я и предложил, раз не ясно, что хочется. А ты, что уже разлюбил SVG? Ты, то почему возражаешь? Я же не настаиваю, что это решение, это вариант решения. Возможно, будут варианты решения на CSS, я не против, только за. Чем больше решений, тем лучше

Comment: я разлюбил svg ? ты что ? просто в этом вопросе не может быть ответа так как через css писать attribute svg не возможно ...

Comment: @spoon100500 а если и прямоугольник и треугольник одним контуром или клипом то проблем вообще не будет

Comment: @spoon100500 или внизу на градиенте ответ - тоже хороший вариант